# In Morocco, do you get better prices for paying in Euros?

Tags: money, tips-and-tricks, morocco

On a previous trip to Tunisia, I was slightly surprised to discover that many tourist-focused vendors (though not all) offered two prices, one in Euros and one in Dinar, with the Euro price quite a lot better than the official exchange rate would've worked out as. Annoyingly, I hadn't known this in advance, so hadn't brought any euro notes with me. (I suspect that currency exchange restrictions had something to do with it, as I've had a similar experience with EUR and USD pricing in Sri Lanka which also has restrictions)

Reading the [money section of the UK FCO advice for Morocco](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/morocco/money), I see that the Moroccan Dirham (MAD) is non-convertible. That lead me to wonder if the same thing might apply there too.

So, at touristy places in Morocco, is there typically any financial advantage for paying with Euros rather than Moroccan Dirhams? (i.e. should I pack some euro notes, or just my no-overseas-fee card with which to withdraw dirhams)

Comment: From my experience visiting Marrakesh, the prices were definitely worse in Euros than paying in the local currency Dirhams.  I suppose there's no harm in bringing fresh Euro notes just in case.  Mind you, never pay the "listed" prices, always haggle.

Answer (score 6):

No, not at all

(short answer, read the rest if interested)

that is not the case. Tunisia has rampant inflation and irrealistic "official" change rate. In Morocco 20+ years ago, it was slightly advantagous, not anymore. before the citizens could only legaly convert a ridiculously small sum for their foreign travel so everyone had to resort to black market, so foreign currencies were seeked and citizens willing to pay more (just a bit more) for them. the legal amount authorised to be exchanged has steadily grown killing the black market.

So, no, invariably when you are quoted a euro price it is more expensive. it might seem cheaper sometimes, but that's because they overquote in dirham, and expect you to half the amount at least, while in your currency, they expect less bargaining... but in most cases, the euro quote is much higher because they figure you are an ignorant tool who juges prices from a european perspective...from my experience, living in morroco, when i am quoted a price in euros it is often 2-3 times the real price.

So no, their used to be a lot of countries like that, but less and less. the last time i found this situation was in cambodia, i knew that and made sure to bring fresh bills.

So, no

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will potentially make some good savings by paying in Euros. Some locals are pretty interested to get Euros as then it is easier for them to trade with Euros than with their local currency. Still take into consideration the fact that some merchants will adjust their price to your nationality (ie budget).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a black currency market then, where you can change the euros for a better rate?

Comment: is there a source to this info? or an experience you can share?

Comment: This is just my experience, I have been there :)

Comment: "easier for them to trade with Euros" is non-sense, it is a lot harder. You may have been had, if they offered a cheaper "euro deal" the dirham price  was nowhere near real. But yes merchants will adjust prices depending on percieved wealth, and nationality to a mesure, a dirty barefoot british hippie will probably get a beter deal than a local in a business suit.